# How to automate testing of Flutter application on Linux-Desktop via Github Actions CI

Tags: flutter, github-actions, gui-testing, flutter-integration-test, flutter-linux

We want to make our integration tests work on Linux desktop (ubuntu-latest) via Github Actions.

The command is

```sh
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
flutter test -d linux integration_test
```

But we always get an error:

```
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly, or never started.
//...
TestDeviceException(Unable to start the app on the device.)
  package:flutter_tools/src/test/integration_test_device.dart 61:7  IntegrationTestTestDevice.start
```

Can Github Actions not handle the GPU / GUI related stuff fast enough on the CPU or what is going on. Is this even possible?
I found only [one repository](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/89993a6339cf74594e88bc48f861d0c95e8b21ea/melos.yaml#L197) which call similar command for a linux environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63125480/5164462), where `Xvfb` was mentioned in an answer, it worked:

```yaml
jobs:
  linux:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ...
    steps:
        run: |
          export DISPLAY=:99
          sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
          flutter test -d linux integration_test
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `GabrielBB/xvfb-action@v1.6` github action to enable xvfb.

```
      - name: flutter test
        uses: GabrielBB/xvfb-action@v1.6
        with:
          working-directory: ./examples/flutter
          run: |
            flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
            flutter test integration_test/basics_test.dart -d linux
```

Answer (score 0):

This was enough for me -

`xvfb-run flutter test -d linux integration_test`

`xvfb` is pre-installed on [Ubuntu 22.04](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#installed-apt-packages:%7E:text=1.5.4%2D2-,xvfb,-2%3A21.1.4%2D2ubuntu1.7) Runner Image.

Credits -

1. [FrBrGeorge's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69602214/3302026)